# XSD Not Picked Up by XMLBeans Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate XMLBeans classes using maven plugin. I have configured this in my POM file, but every time I do a clean install, I see this in the debug logs:

> [DEBUG] Number of XSD Files: 0
>
> [DEBUG] Number of WSDL Files: 0
>
> [INFO] Nothing to generate.

My plugin is defined as:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.002</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xsd-to-java-xmlbeans</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <classGenerationDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\java\</classGenerationDirectory>
                        <compiler>1.8</compiler>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <download>true</download>
                        <outputJar>subInterfaceXSD.jar</outputJar>
                        <quiet>false</quiet>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\XSDFiles\</schemaDirectory>
                        <generatedSchemaDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\XSDFiles\</generatedSchemaDirectory>
                        <sourceGenerationDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\java\</sourceGenerationDirectory>                            
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a buggy plugin. Switching to an older version helped.